# R check if a list of TRUE/FALSE values evaluate to TRUE

Tags: r, list, vector, predicate

I am relatively new to R so sorry if this is basics. I have this loop that have a condition inside that compares between 2 lists and return a vector of TRUE/FALSE values. What I really need to check is if this vector includes ONLY TRUE values (meaning the 2 lists are identical)

```
for ( i in 1:(length(sessions_items_list)-1)){
  if (sessions_items_list[[i]]==sessions_items_list[[i+1]]){
    identical_sessions_df [i,1] <- names(sessions_items_list[i])
    identical_sessions_df [i,2] <- names(sessions_items_list[i+1])
    #identical_sessions_df [i,3] <- sessions_items_list[[i]]
    #identical_sessions_df [i,4] <- sessions_items_list[[i+1]]
  }
}
```

Here is some data:

```
> sessions_items_list[[2]]
 [1] "111502665618" "111505397996" "121238758674" "121480200508" "131159477858" "161469302097" "161474935929" "171526802604" "231197187139" "231381216285" "251502101205" "261650031415"
[13] "261652085962" "261652452940" "271538491767" "281398254987" "291227243345" "311065441334" "321561638226" "321566237993" "331042848072" "331251405185" "331366646532" "361096154736"
[25] "381043841996"
> sessions_items_list[[3]]
 [1] "111502665618" "111505397996" "121238758674" "131159477858" "161469302097" "161474935929" "171526802604" "231197187139" "231381216285" "251502101205" "261647474153" "261650031415"
[13] "261652085962" "261652452940" "271538491767" "281398254987" "291227243345" "311065441334" "321561638226" "321566237993" "331042848072" "331251405185" "331366646532" "361096154736"
[25] "381043841996"
```

Here is the condition result example:

```
> sessions_items_list[[2]]==sessions_items_list[[3]]
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Is there a simple function to check of this list of predicates evaluate to TRUE (all values are TRUE)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe try the `all` function:

```
> x <- c(rep(TRUE, 5), FALSE)
> y <- c(rep(TRUE, 6))
> all(x)
[1] FALSE
> all(y)
[1] TRUE
```

As its name says, it checks if all the values are TRUE.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe goes without saying, but I often want to check the obverse scenario, i.e. if a vector includes only FALSE values. For that case, check if `any` value is true, and if none is (which gives you FALSE), negate it:

```
> x <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
> y <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
> z <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
> !any(x)
[1] FALSE
> !any(y)
[1] FALSE
> !any(z)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers are all vectors, whereas the title of the post says "list".
To check if a *list* of logicals evaluates to TRUE, simply `unlist()` before checking.

```
> x <- list(rep(TRUE, 5), FALSE)
> y <- list(rep(TRUE, 6))

> all(x)
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
In addition: Warning message:
In all(x) : coercing argument of type 'list' to logical

> unlist(x) |> all()
[1] FALSE
> unlist(y) |> all()
[1] TRUE
```